# "Program can not display web page" error while taking snapshot HtmlCapture.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, windows-server-2008, webclient

I have an `ASP.NET` web application developed in `Visual Studio 2008` which uses `HtmlCapture.Net` (www.polestarsoft.com/products/htmlcapture-net/) to take snapshot of some pages.

For example, application has to take snap shot of this page:
http://www.yillikfabrikasi.com/KullaniciYillikSayfasiVersion2ResimlerArkaPlan.aspx?username=bolatug@gmail.com&yillikId=ab05ab4c-138b-4332-b4ca-78484bae5b3e&refresher=31b8ff91-00a0-4122-bea8-87efd879ad83

It was working fine until I moved the application from `Windows Server 2003` to `Windows Server 2008 (64 bit)`.  Now all images the program takes includes the error message "This Program cannot display webpage" instead of the actual page. You can see how it should be in the link above. [here is the picture the application takes](http://www.yillikfabrikasi.com/errortr.jpg)

I tried to configure the `app pool` to `DefaultAppPool` with identity set to Local System account and  the classic `app Pool` with the same identity.  Both configurations fails to take the snapshot.

I have logged the `URL` used to take the snapshot and I can see the correct page in a browser and take a snapshot with the `HtmlCapture.Net` application.  So I am sure the `URL` is correct.

What could be the reason for this problem?  I think some configuration or security issue prevents the `HtmlCapture.Net` dll from opening the URL. But I don't have any idea how to fix it.  So any opinion is appreciated.

Comment: perhaps look into enabling 32-bit in IIS

Answer (score 0):

That component seems to use the installed webbrowser (IE) via ActiveX or similar.

Windows Server 2008 has (compared to Windows Server 2003) enhanced security on several levels... including:

- [IE enhanced security configuration](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815141/en-us)
- Different security model for IIS
- Different security model for Windows Services (which IIS happens to be)
- etc.

Any of the above might lead to the behaviour you see... IMHO it is best to contact the vendor of the component regarding system configuration...

An alternative is to use a component wich does not suffer from the above mentioned aspects - namely does not use IE or ActiveX for that functionality... there are some components (mostly commercial) out there... IF that is an option for let me know - I can post some links...